# This is a simple javascript syntax issue

Tags: javascript

I want to know if these two things are the same. In my brain they are. I am overall just trying to understand the javascript syntax better. In my brain these are the same. Please let me know why I am crazy! Thanks,

is this first one

```
if (edited === 'true' || edited === '')
```

the same as this?

```
if (edited == 'true' && '')
```

Comment: No they are not. In one condition, you are using `||` and second `&&`

Comment: The first one has a possibility of being true. The second one doesn't!

Comment: Think `if (expression && expression)`. Where each expression evaluates to either `true` or `false` and `&&` evaluates the second expression if the first one is `true`.

Comment: Please read about [Logical Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) and [Comparison Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) at MDN.

Comment: @user3174713 - Please choose an `accepted answer` by using the `green checkbox` next to the answer that helped the most. This will allow future coders a reference to the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.  They are *completely* different.

In the first one, it checks to see if either `edited === 'true'` or `edited === ''` is true.

In the second one, it checks to see if both `edited == 'true'` and `''` are true.  `''` converts to `false`, so the second one is like doing `edited == 'true' && false` or just simply `false`.

Answer (score 4):

These are called `logical operators`.

**Here is what each one does:**

`&&` - Tests if BOTH conditions are true

`||` - Tests if EITHER conditions are true

---

For your code:

`if (edited === 'true' || edited === '')` **you could actually do...**

`if (edited === 'true || '')`
**Tests if** `edited === true OR false` and if either is true, `run it`.

`if (edited === 'true' && '')`
**Tests if** `edited === true AND false`

**Clearly the `last one` will never work, as `edited` is considered the same as `false`, `null`, `0`, etc.**

Comment: @user3174713 - Please choose an accepted answer by using the green checkbox next to the answer that helped the most. This will allow future coders a reference to the issue.

Answer (score 1):

No.  Empty quotes always returns a "falsy" value, so your second test will either return true && false, or false && false.

Comment: I get it now. I have a long ways to go it seems!